# how to setAttribute(s) for multiple tags at once

Tags: javascript, input, setattribute

How would I go about setting 3 separate input tags to disable at once? After the user enters a time I would like to disable the input fields, then enable them when the time runs out. I know how to add the logic, I'm just having a hard time adding "disabled" to all of them at once.

```
<div id="inputFields">
    <h3>Enter Time</h3>
    <input id="hours" type="text" value="" name="hours" placeholder="Hours" maxlength="2"> <span>:</span>
    <input id="minutes" type="text" value="" name="min" placeholder="Minutes" maxlength="2"> <span>:</span>
    <input id="seconds" type="text" value="" name="seconds" placeholder="Seconds" maxlength="2">
</div>
```

Would I have to loop through them? Or could I access them as children of #inputFields? Or neither? Any suggestions would be appreciated...Thanks.

Comment: You would have to loop through them.

Comment: Using jquery you can do: $('#hours, #minutes, #seconds').attr('disabled','disabled');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery:

```
$('#inputFields > input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Which sets the attribute for every `input` that is a direct descendant of `#inputFields`.

Another option:

```
$('#hours,#minutes,#seconds').prop('disabled', true);
```

Or if using pure Javascript:

```
['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'].forEach(function (elemId) {
    document.getElementById(elemId).setAttribute('disabled', true);
});
```

Should work nice too. This is as close to "all of them at once" that you can get.

Comment: Just use `.disabled = true`. (`prop('disabled', true)` is also more correct.)

Comment: @minitech you're right about `prop()`, I'll edit it. Not so sure about `.disabled`, I think I like `setAttribute()` better - it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to loop through them, you can do whatever you want with them.

```
$('#inputFields').children('input').each(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

e.g

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Don't know why your answer was downvoted, because you presented another correct way of doing it. I'm upvoting you back to 0.

Comment: Well this happens at stackoverflow ... when I was adding my answer there was NO answer, when I pressed "add answer" someone bet me to it by 2 seconds or so. The next person thought I copied it and downvoted it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of packing your `input` elements into a `div`, you could properly make them child elements of a `form` element.

This would have the advantage, that there is already a collection of `form` elements in HTML, that you can easily access in JavaScript using `document.forms[ ]` or just `forms[ ]` , and their children with `forms[ ].elements[ ]`.

The forms as well as their chilren can either be called by their index or their `name` attribute, as like

```
 var firstInput = forms['myInputForm'].elements[0];
```

for example, so that you then could loop through this selection and perform any changes you want.

**EDIT**

Given the fact, your `input` elements do have a `name` attribute anyway, you could write it like this

```
['hours', 'min', 'seconds'].forEach(function (name) {

  document.forms['inputFields'].elements[name].setAttribute('disabled', true);

});
```

in your script and `<form name="inputFields">` instead of your `div` in HTML.

For containing `input` elements, the `form` element suits better than the `div` element, and, as mentioned before, you wouldn't have to search the whole DOM for your `input` elements, as there is already a HTML Collection that you can access using JavaScript the way described above.